# binary search tree augmented to implement min and max operations in O(1) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, implementation, data-augmentation

I'm trying to implement binary search tree operations `MIN` and `MAX` efficiently, in `O(1)` time. I see if `BST` is balanced, then these take `O(lgn)` in the worst-case; otherwise, `O(h)`, where h is the height of the root of the bst, worst-case runtime. But both of them isn't efficient considering that (max/min)heap provide `O(1)` time to get `min` and `max`. I've tried to augment bst to get max and min in constant time, but I got doubts on it. The implementation is in C programming language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct node {
    int key;
    struct node* left, * right, * parent, * min, * max;
}augmented_bst;

augmented_bst* find_min(augmented_bst* node) {
    if (!node)
        return node;
    return node->min;
}

augmented_bst* next_larger(augmented_bst* node) {
    if (!node)
        return node;
    if (node->right)
        return node->right->min;
    
    while (node->parent && node->parent->right == node)
        node = node->parent;
    return node->parent;
}

augmented_bst* new_Node(int x) {
    augmented_bst* node = (augmented_bst*)malloc(sizeof(augmented_bst));
    assert(node != NULL);
    node->key = x;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    node->min = node->max = node;
    return node;
}

void insert(augmented_bst** root, int x) {
    augmented_bst* node = new_Node(x);
    if (!node)
        return;
    if (!*root)
        *root = node;
    else if ((*root)->key > node->key) {
        if ((*root)->min->key > node->key)
            (*root)->min = node;
        if (!(*root)->left) {
            (*root)->left = node;
            node->parent = *root;
        }
        else {
            insert(&(*root)->left, x);
        }
    }
    else {
        if ((*root)->max->key < node->key)
            (*root)->max = node;
        if (!(*root)->right) {
            (*root)->right = node;
            node->parent = *root;
        }
        else {
            insert(&(*root)->right, x);
        }
    }
}

augmented_bst* search_tree(augmented_bst* root, int x) {
    if (root == NULL || root->key == x)
        return root;
    if (root->key > x)
        return search_tree(root->left, x);
    return search_tree(root->right, x);
}

void TRANSPLANT(augmented_bst* root, augmented_bst* u, augmented_bst* v) {
    if (u->parent == NULL)
        root = v;
    else if (u->parent->left == u)
        u->parent->left = v;
    else
        u->parent->right = v;
    if (v != NULL)
        v->parent = u->parent;
}

void fixMin(augmented_bst** node) {
    if (!*node)
        return;
    augmented_bst* current = *node;
    while (current->parent && current->parent->left == current) {
        current->parent->min = current->min;
        current = current->parent;
    }
}

void fixMax(augmented_bst** node) {
    if (!*node)
        return;
    augmented_bst* current = node;
    while (current->parent && current->parent->right == current) {
        current->parent->max = current->max;
        current = current->parent;
    }
}

void DELETE(augmented_bst** root, int x) {
    augmented_bst* node = search_tree(*root, x);
    assert(node != NULL);
    if (!node->right) {
        TRANSPLANT(*root, node, node->left);
        fixMin(&node);
    }
    else if (!node->left) {
        TRANSPLANT(*root, node, node->right);
        fixMax(&node);
    }
    else {
        augmented_bst* temp = next_larger(node);
        if (node->right != temp) {
            TRANSPLANT(*root, temp, temp->right);
            fixMin(&temp->right);
            temp->right = node->right;
            temp->right->parent = temp;
            temp->max = node->right->max;
        
        }
        TRANSPLANT(*root, node, temp);
        fixMax(&temp);
        temp->left = node->left;
        temp->left->parent = temp;
        temp->min = temp->left->min;
    }
}
```

**NOTES:** some procedures in the code is take from CLRS. I put whole implementation thinking someone might need it. My problem is with the `DELETE` procedure, but you can suggest anything about other parts of the code. If you think this can be done in better way, please state it. I used `fixMin` and `fixMax` functions four times inside `DELETE` procedure. Can we do it better? If yes, how? Is there a better (or different) way to implement `DELETE` procedure? I appreciate your answers and am open to any suggestions about anything.

Comment: Unless you have a problem getting it to work, it should go on Code Review.

Comment: My 2¢: when I augment a tree with a synthesized attribute (function of children and other fields of self), I invariably wrap assignments to `left` and `right` in a function. In this case, `set_left` would set the left child and update `min` and the child's `parent`, while `set_right` would set the right child and update `max` and the child's `parent`. The compiler will inline these on any reasonable setting.

Comment: (1/2) On the other hand, for this specific attribute, I'd actually be inclined to either 1. store min and max at the root only and handle deletion using the O(h)-time algorithm, thus avoiding the space overheads; or 2. replace the `min` and `max` fields with `prev` and `next` to form a doubly linked list in sorted order. This list should have a sentinel and be circularly linked. Then deletion is really easy (from the deleted node, set `prev->next = next;` and `next->prev = prev;`).

Comment: (2/2) For insertion, initialize `prev` and `next` to the sentinel node on descent. Whenever the new value compares greater than a node, update `prev` to that node. Whenever the new value compares less than a node, update `next` to that node. Splice in the new node by setting `node->prev = prev; node->next = next; prev->next = node; next->prev = node;`. The min and max are the `next` and `prev` respectively of the sentinel.